# How do I write a wav file purely using ipd.audio in python?

Tags: python, scipy, ipython, artificial-intelligence, librosa

I am creating a neural network that produces musical instrument like sounds on a server that then pulls that data to iOS application. Therefore, the process must be automated. (More on that later.)

Here is the strange thing though when listening to the audio using ipd.audio sounds perfectly fine on download and in the notebook. But using any other library it causes it to sound horrid.

What libraries I have tried so far:

- Scipy
- Liborsa
- Soundfile

If I can just programmatically call ipd.audio to write the wav file to a specific location then I will be set.

Code Snippet:
[image]

(Please be careful when listening to the files in the zip file.  Lower your audio please I don't want to hurt anyone ears...)

Link to the audio files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10AaDi_ITOCQv2hsxd9_UDV2OYLWd1_Da

Comment: Thank you in advance for any help stack overflow! :3

Comment: How is `wave` created?  Is it a numpy array?  If so, what are `wave.shape`, `wave.dtype`, `wave.min()` and `wave.max()`?

Comment: It's a numpy array with dimensions of (10,000,). It was created using pretty midi and fluidsynth to generate the wave.

Comment: What are `wave.dtype`, `wave.max()` and `wave.min()`?  I don't understand the sequence of actions that you are taking that lead to a problem.  I just played the file that you linked to using VLC, and it doesn't sound horrid, but I don't know what it is supposed to sound like.  Which function did you use to create that file?  Do you have a file that was created with the scipy function?  If you read the file back in, is the data different?

Comment: Ok the dtype is float64.
The max is 965.0
The min is -1528.0.
The orginal audio or correct audio is on the goolge drive and is called IP Audio Sound which was created using ipd.audio. In the zip file is me trying different libs to write the file.

Comment: I didn't try reading back in the data from the files that seemed screwed up that's a good step for de-bugging this.

Comment: The data seems to be exactly the same....max, min, shape, sampling rate. etc.

Comment: I just don't understand why I am getting different results...

Comment: I think I understand it now. Since they all are having the same output I think it has to do with the default nbits for ipd.audio

Comment: To anyone else having this problem it is as simple as setting the bool norm in librosa.output.write_wav to 1. That was dumb...